# Finite Decimals - a question I found online with no solution given.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

Here's the full question:

> Show that there exist no finite decimals $a=0.\overline{a_1a_2a_3...a_n}$ such that when its digits are rearranged to a different decimal $b=0.\overline{a_{b_1}a_{b_2}a_{b_3}...a_{b_n}}$, $a+b=1$.

Does this simply mean the digits are rearranged to form another decimal, with every digit used only once? For example $0.123456789$ is rearranged to $0.234567891$?

How would you go about solving this question?

EDIT: Here is the link to where I found this question. It's quite a puzzling question regarding the use of the overline. It states that $a$ and $b$ are finite decimals, yet they use the overline?

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Random_Problem#Medium_Problem

EDIT 2: I think it's safe to assume that the overline is used wrongly, so we can ignore the overline. The question is asking us to prove that there are no finite decimals that fit those conditions. So the real question can be posed as follows:

> Show that there exist no finite decimals $a=0.a_1a_2a_3...a_n$ such that when its digits are rearranged to a different decimal $b=0.a_{b_1}a_{b_2}a_{b_3}...a_{b_n}$, $a+b=1$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144848/discussion-on-question-by-maximus-t-finite-decimals-a-question-i-found-online); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

(Note that I abused notation and am relabelling $b = 0.b_1 b_2 \ldots b_n$ instead of $b = 0.a_{b_1} a_{b_2} \ldots a_{b_n} $ for simplicity.)

Here's a hint-solution (IE How to go about solving this) under the constraints of

1. $a = 0.a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n, b=0.b_1 b_2 \ldots b_n$ have finitely many digits.
2. The same digit does not reappear in the same location: $a_i \neq b_i$ (So we can't swap a (say) 5 with another 5. In particular, this disallows the $0.455 + 0.545$ counterexample.)
3. Each digit is used the same number of times: Let $C_i, D_i$ be the number of times that the digit $i$ appears in $a$ and $b$ respectively. Then $C_i = D_i \, \forall i$.  Note that the digits could repeat.

**Hints:**

- Obvious observation: Show that $(a_n, b_n) \neq (0, 0), (5, 5)$.
- Obvious observation: What can we say about $a_n + b_n$?

  - This gets around Thomas' pesky observations of trailing 0's, though we don't end up conditioning on the total number of digits.
- Obvious observation: Show that $a_i + b_i = 9$ for $ i = 1 $ to $n-1$.
- How to exploit the condition: This suggest that $C_i $ and $D_{9-i}$ are very similar, and likewise for $C_{9-i} $ and $D_i$. So we have something like $ C_i \approx D_{9-i} = C_{9-1} \approx D_i$.

  - When does equality not hold throughout?
- Study the counterexample: If we allowed for $(a_n, b_n) = (5, 5)$, why could we then have $C_i = D_i \forall i$?

  - This arguably is the **key observation** to make.
- Arriving at a contradiction: Conditioning on how these sets may differ, arrive at a contradiction of the form $C_j \neq D_j$, hence $a, b$ are not a "rearrangement" of each other.

**Corollary:** Constraint 2 can be weakened to $(a_n, b_n) \neq (5, 5), (0,0)$, and the rest of the proof still works. Of course it's not as "nice" of a statement.

**Corollary:** If $a + b = 1$ and $(a_n, b_n) \neq (5, 5), (0,0)$, then what can we say about $C_i, D_i$, conditional on $a_n, b_n$?
Note: One may approach this problem by studying this first, even though it significantly relaxes the constraints.